# How to validate the request date format coming in the request header in a spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-time

I have a controller like below-

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/initiatiation-task/v1")
public class LoginInitiationTaskController {

    private final LoginInitiationTaskService loginInitiationTaskService;

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<InitiateLoginResponse> initiateLogin(
            @Valid @RequestHeader("Date")  @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z") ZonedDateTime date) {

        // ...
    }

}
```

I need to validate the request date format. The above config doesn't works. I also tried with the below one -

```
@JsonFormat( pattern = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", timezone="GMT") ZonedDateTime date
```

When a date is sent in the header via postman
[image]

Spring throws an exception

> org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException:
> Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
> 'java.time.ZonedDateTime'; Failed to convert from type
> [java.lang.String] to type
> [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader
> @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat java.time.ZonedDateTime]
> for value 'Sun, 01 Jan 2023 06:49:53 GMT'

Comment: Just a guess here: could be a problem with your locale, i.e. if your system's locale isn't English names like "Sun" and "Jan" might not be parseable (the system might expect different names according to your system locale). Can you try with numbers only?

Comment: What I would suggest is to change the data type to String from ZonedDateTime and then perform a validation check for the format. That should do the job.

Comment: @Thomas When i use yyyy-MM-dd with LocalDate, it works fine.

Comment: Did you try with `ZonedDateTime` but a numeric only representation of data, time and timezone?

Comment: @Thomas this works on my local machine - `String requestDate = "Sun, 01 Jan 2023 06:49:53 GMT"; 
String format = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'";
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format).withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
ZonedDateTime thenZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(requestDate, parser);`

Comment: That's not the format you're using in your controller though. If you're trying it independently you should make sure you're using the exact same format and input - just to rule out any incompatibilities there.

Comment: @Thomas - i have tried with all combinations for GMT and Z. None of them works. In a standalone java program, it works but not with the annotation as above.

Comment: I believe the good and correct formatter to use is `DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME`. Save yourself from fiddling with your own format pattern string.